# Как с помощью вордпресса отправить данные с моей формы на почту?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

в плагинах я как понял нельзя использовать свою вёрстку, а предлагают создать новую форму.

Comment: можно использовать cf7 он достаточно не плохо настраивается в плане верстки

Comment: Всё можно. Но для начала нужно научиться нормально задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

пример реализации кастомной формы с отправкой через ajax. Само собой функционал для примера и не для того чтоб его использовать на сайте нужно доработать валидацию, но в данном случае вопрос не о защите.

html часть

```
<form id="custom-form">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('name_of_action','name_of_field'); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

php часть. подробнее о функции wp_mail() можно прочитать по этой ссылке
[wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_form_send', 'send_form_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_form_send', 'send_form_data');

function send_form_data(){
    if ( ! isset($_POST['name_of_field']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_of_field'], 'name_of_action') ){
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    $to = 'sendto@example.com';
    $subject = 'Tема письма';
    $body = 'Данные из формы или любой другой контент';
    $headers = ['Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'];

    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) ) {
        wp_send_json_success();
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}
```

js часть

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

    let sendForm = {
        init(){
            this.events();
        },
        events(){
            $('form#custom-form').on('submit', this.sendForm.bind( this ) );
        },
        sendForm( e ){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax( {
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  // url лучше брать из json
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'custom_form_send',
                    nonce: $( e.target ).find('[name="name_of_field"]').val(),
                }
            } ).success( function( response ) {
                if ( response.success ) {
                    console.log('success');
                } else {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            } );
        }
    };

    sendForm.init();

} );
```

Comment: Уже за wp_mail( 'to@test.com ' (да ещё и без пояснений что это за мыло ) надо руки отрывать. Нафига вообще давать опасный код с комментами что его использовать нельзя.

Comment: Этот код чтобы показать пример как это можно сделать,  не нужно выдумывать не существующих проблем

Comment: Это пример как НЕНУЖНО делать. А что бы не выдумывать не существующих проблеме достаточно использовать плагины для обратки

Comment: если вы все решаете через сетап плагинов, то дело ваше

Comment: Я знаю что это всего лишь пример и Вы это обозначили, но претензия скорее всего в отсутствии каких-либо средств очистки и защиты. В примере Вы просто принимаете данные из `$_POST` без их очистки, а также используете ajax без  [nonce](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/plugin/bezopasnost/odnorazovye-chisla). Вот и получается что в Вашем примере XSS и CSRF уязвимости. Вы можете это все прекрасно знать, но пользователь задавший вопрос, скорее всего не в курсе этих тонкостей. Плагин посоветовали, так как в плагине вопросы безопасности учтены.

Comment: выпрос был не о безопасности, а о том как можно отправить письмо из формы используя wp.

Comment: @Simon если что "претензии" прежде всего в том что а) это дыра б) не заработает на большинстве нормальных хостингах. Т.е.данный  ответ - опасный мусор, а не помощь. А плагинофобия - зло не меньшее чем плагинофлия.

Comment: нет смысла в холиваре, когда ты не понимаешь абстракции